# Read date from file name

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime

What I need to do is to convert a string that I obtain reading a file's name, in the form of `yyyyMMdd.log` and transform it in an object of type 'DateTime'.

The command that I use to create the file is:

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(FileDailyEnergySavingUpperName, string.Concat(date.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), ".log"));
```

How do I convert back the string to date?

Edit: looking online I found this: 
`DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(myString, "yyyyMMdd",null);`

Is it correct?

Comment: Do you not have access to the 'date' variable anymore?

Comment: try `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.TryParse` functions.

Comment: No, the file is used to store logs that I will read in the future, so I don't have access to the date variable when I read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at

> DateTime.TryParseExact

E.g.

```
DateTime dateValue; 
bool parsed = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTime, 
                       "yyyyMMdd", 
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                       DateTimeStyles.None, 
                       out dateValue);
```

Comment: I am aware of that function, but I don't know how to set the format to read my string.

Comment: I edited my answer, to make it use TryParseExact, which takes in the format string.

Comment: Pleasure, just remember to check the result (parsed) to make sure the conversion was successful.

Comment: Sure, I put the TryParse inside an if.

Comment: Is it too much to ask for a vote up? I am trying to reach 15 reputation so I can vote other people's answers, and I am 2 short. Could you do me this favor?